# Template content not updating on consecutive calls Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templating

Very new to Angular and after searching all over the show I simply cannot find a solution to my problem.

I have the following function in a directive/controller:

```
ModalIssueController.prototype.openModal = function (e, issue) {

        this._dataService.getMain().then(function (model) {

            this._$scope.modalIssue.open = true;
            this._$scope.modalIssue.issue = model.getIssueById(issue);

            this._windowService.setModalOpen(true);

        }.bind(this));
    };
```

The above function is called each time the user clicks on a different issue from a list. This opens a modal and shows the content related to issue.

When the modal is closed via a close button, the following is called:

```
ModalIssueController.prototype.closeModal = function () {
        this._$scope.modalIssue.open = false;
        this._windowService.setModalOpen(false);

        this._$timeout(function () {
            this._$location.url('/');
        }.bind(this));
    };
```

The problem is, even though I can see that the value of this._$scope.modalIssue.issue changes to reflect the new issue that was clicked, the content in the modal never changes, but instead, continues to show the data from the first selected issue ;(

Am I missing something here? Is there an additional step I need to add to ensure that the data in the template is updated?

Here is the directive 'set-up':

```
var ModalIssueDirective = function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            scope: true,
            controller: ModalIssueController,
            templateUrl: '/app/lorax/directives/modal-issue.tpl.html'
        };
    };
```

And here is the template I am populating:

```
<section class="modal modal--fade-show modal--issue" ng-show="modalIssue.open" >
  <a href="#" class="modal__close modal__close-absolute icon-close" data-lorax-prevent-default ng-click="modalIssue.closeModal()">Close</a>
  <h1 class="detail-header-title">{{::modalIssue.issue.getTitle()}}</h1>
  <div class="detail-main__copy">{{::modalIssue.issue.getNarrative()}}</div>

  <header class="detail-link__header">
    <h1>{{::modalIssue.issue.getMiscLocale().mozDoingLabel}}</h1>
  </header>
  <p class="detail-link__copy">{{::modalIssue.issue.getMozActionCopy()}}</p>
  <a ng-if="::modalIssue.issue.getMozActionLink().length === 1" href="{{::modalIssue.issue.getMozActionLink()[0].url}}" class="btn detail-link__btn">{{::modalIssue.issue.getMozActionLink()[0].copy}}</a>
  <a ng-if="::modalIssue.issue.getMozActionLink().length > 1" ng-repeat="link in ::modalIssue.issue.getMozActionLink()" href="{{link.url}}" class="detail-link__multiple">{{link.copy}}<span class="icon-arrow-right"></span></a>


  <header class="detail-link__header">
    <h1>{{::modalIssue.issue.getMiscLocale().yourDoingLabel}}</h1>
  </header>
  <p class="detail-link__copy">{{::modalIssue.issue.getYourActionCopy()}}</p>
  <a ng-if="::modalIssue.issue.getYourActionLink().length === 1" href="{{::modalIssue.issue.getYourActionLink()[0].url}}" class="btn detail-link__btn">{{::modalIssue.issue.getYourActionLink()[0].copy}}</a>
  <a ng-if="::modalIssue.issue.getYourActionLink().length > 1" ng-repeat="link in ::modalIssue.issue.getYourActionLink()" href="{{link.url}}" class="detail-link__multiple">{{link.copy}}<span class="icon-arrow-right"></span></a>
</section>
```

Thank you in advance for any assistance that can be provided here.

Answer (score 1):

So, turns out :: in Angular templates defines a one-time binding. This essentially means that as soon as, for example, the following expression has been run:

```
{{::modalIssue.issue.getTitle()}}
```

and it returned a value that is not undefined, it is considered stable and the expression will never be run again. So, removing :: from each of the relevant lines in the template resolved the issue.

Docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression (@see One-Time Binding)

Comment: That bit me last week.  It worked exactly like I didn't expect it to.